# How do I add a javascript function to button_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `button_to` function on my view in a rails application that currently call a method in the controller, but I'd also like it to execute some javascript as well. I'd like to prompt the user to enter some info that I'll send back to the controller and use later

Here's my current code.

```
   <%= button_to 'Mark Learned' , song_rank_marklearned_path(song_rank_id: song_rank.id), remote: true , method: :post, onclick: "marklearned(#{song_rank.id})" %>
```

Comment: You’ll need to write custom JavaScript. Seems like you have an onclick handler in place already.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script tag in your html.erb file you can write some custom JS.

```
<script>
  function marklearned() {
    var songRankId = <%= song_rank.id %> // This can reference your helper_method or instance variable

    // fetch call to post to your db
  }
</script>
```